# Intuitive explanation on "Generalization "

Tags: intuition, generalization

I recently worked on **Generalization** of Gradients.

If I'm asked to find Generalization of Gradients or for Dirichlet distribution, etc. I'll do it correctly like a machine. But I didn't understand it. I didn't get the purpose of it. I didn't get the feel of it.

Well, I can't explain the concept of "Generalization" to a layman or grandma.

- **I'm not clear on when and why to perform a Generalization?**
- **How would you explain "Generalization" to a layman?**

Comment: Generalization of what?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal of generalization is that what is demonstrated on a small scale applies also on a large scale. A model might perform well on training data, but generalization refers to how well it performs on new, unseen data. For example, a model that overfits to errors in the training data will not generalize well.